# Maximum height for a given width of a wall?

Tags: gravity

Say I have a wall that can support 8 feet of height for a width of 20 inches. Is there any way, from this information alone, to determine how much more height this material can support by increasing its width to 2 feet?

Comment: Why would you expect the wider wall could be built higher?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use this information without a model, that tells how height support changes with the width, i.e. a function H(W). 
However, you can assume that it is approximately linear or quadratic, depending on the contexto of your question.